# Transplanting Jack in the Pulpit

Tags: transplanting

I came across a jack in the pulpit in the woods of a local park. Sitting there all by itself. The park is heavily hunted for all sorts of stuff and I want to save this thing. When and how would be the best time and way to transplant this to our land about an hour and a half south of here? How fast do these spread?[image]

Comment: It is likely to be illegal to (attempt to) transplant it from a public park.

Comment: I've checked and it's OK in Ohio.

Answer (score 4):

If its growing wild in a public, wooded area, leave it where it is. If you want some of this plant for your garden, buy some - they're corms, and now is not the time to attempt to dig it up -this is best done in autumn, after all the foliage has disappeared, when you likely won't be able to find it again anyway, luckily, considering the ethics of the situation. You could, though, go back when the red berries are present and take a few of those and grow on from the seed. More information about this plant in the link below, including hints on where to buy it, and how to grow from seed, together with growing conditions

http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/yard-garden/flowers/jack-in-the-pulpit/

Comment: I agree. No need to move it as they are for sale at nurseries and even grocery stores where I live.